# How to increment and decrement an output voltage by using two buttons?

Tags: arduino-uno, c++, pwm, analogread, hardware

I'm trying to create a code using an Arduino Uno board to increment and decrement the output voltage of the Arduino Uno which is 5 volts and I need to step it up to 10 volts which I have done below.

The things that are missing on the schematic are two buttons. I want to be able to increment 0.5 volts with each press of Button-A until the Arduino is at 5 volts. With Button-B I want to be able to lower the voltage by 0.5 volts with each press of the button till value is 0.

I can do the calculations and the circuit design but I'm not much of a programmer. I just want to know if anyone can point me in a good direction of where I can get the right code. I have already looked at all the tutorials on the Arduino Website. I do know I have to work with the PWM functions as well as `attachinterrupt()` and `Debounce()` functions. Also, how do I set the increments so that I don't go over, say it takes 10 presses to get to 5 volts on the 11th press have it not do anything so I don't break anything. So can anyone please help me with any suggestions?

I have a low pass filter on the circuit for noise handling and like I said I need to add in the buttons to my schematic.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsMiDk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here is my code I have made. I'm using an LED to test the V<sub>out</sub> aspect. So far I can only get my LED to flicker from 2 to 4 volts and my buttons A and B don't work. Can someone look over my code and see how bad I made this?

```C++
int PWMPin = 6; // output pin supporting PWM  
int buttonApin = 9; // buttonA to pin 9 PWM  
int buttonBpin = 10; // buttonB to pin 10 PWM  
float value = 0; // read the value at 0  
int fadeValue = value;  

void setup()    
{   
  Serial.begin(9600); //initialize serial communication at 9600 baud  
  pinMode(buttonApin, INPUT_PULLUP);   
  pinMode(buttonBpin, INPUT_PULLUP);  
  pinMode(PWMPin, OUTPUT);  
}   
void loop()    
{   
  {  
    int port = analogRead(0);  
    port = map(port, 0, 10, 0, 255);  
    analogWrite(6, port);  
  }  

  {  
  if (digitalRead(buttonApin) == LOW, fadeValue)  
  {  
  // fade from min to max in increments of 25.5 points: basically (0.5 volts)  
  for(int fadeValue = 0 ; fadeValue <= 255; fadeValue +=25.5)   

    digitalWrite(PWMPin, fadeValue);  

    // sets the value (range from 0 to 255):  
   Serial.println(PWMPin);  
   analogWrite(PWMPin, fadeValue);                                       
  }   
  }  

  {   
    if (digitalRead(buttonBpin) == LOW, fadeValue)  
  {  
  // fade from max to min in increments of 25.5 points:  
  for(int fadeValue = 255 ; fadeValue >= 0; fadeValue -=25.5)   

    digitalWrite(PWMPin, fadeValue);  

  // sets the value (range from 0 to 255): basically (0.5 volts)  
  analogWrite(PWMPin, fadeValue);                                     
  }  
  }   
}
```

Comment: I think you need to add a pull-down resistor to the + side of the opamp. Since the input of the opamp is high impedance, the voltage on the + is always 5v even at a low pwm duty cycle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to use debounce to detect if a pin has been definitely pressed. You could also test using interrupts (hint: interrupts can happen multiple times even if you "only" pressed once). So either use Arduino's example of debounce or take a look at the [Bounce2 library](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Bounce) found on their website.

Now that you can check whether or not either button A or B has been pressed, how do you keep track of the voltage to be output? You should use a `counter` variable that will be incremented when button A is pressed and decremented when button B is pressed. Here is a pseudocode:

```C++
if(ButtonA == pressed) 
  counter++; 
else if(ButtonB == pressed) 
  counter--;
```

This `counter` variable can be used to control the output voltage. Remember that the argument for `analogWrite()` function on the Arduino Uno is the duty cycle which takes in values from 0 to 255. So `analogWrite(0)` ≣ 0 Volt and `analogWrite(255)` ≣ 5 Volt. So at the moment, you couldn't just do `analogWrite(counter)` because you would need to press 255 times button A!

Instead, you would need a way to convert your counter to reflect the increment you need. You mentioned that it should require 10 presses to reach 5 Volt at the Arduino output, and the easiest way to accomplish this is to use Arduino's [Map function](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Map). The pseudocode would look like this:

```C++
Output = map(counter, 0, 10, 0, 255); 
analogWrite(Output);
```

Now there is one last step! The map function will limit the output voltage from 0 to 5 Volt so everything will be safe; however, the counter is not limited to 0 to 10. This means that even if the counter is at 15 (because you pressed button A too many times) the voltage will be 5 Volt and you would need to press button B at least 6 times to see the voltage go down! So to limit the counter you could easily implement your own function:

```C++
if(counter >= 10) 
  counter = 10; 
else if (counter<= 0) 
  counter = 0;
```

You could also use Arduino's `constrain()` function which more information can be found on their website.

Hopefully this points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 4):

If all you have to do is to read those 2 buttons, you could just forgo the interrupts and simply poll in the main loop.
The [Bounce2 library](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Bounce) does basically the same.

Also, about the PWM, why not an R-2R?

10V/0.5V + 1 => 21 steps < 32 => 5 bits => 6 resistors.

But it could be more precise, as you would not depend on the oscillator, rather on the precision of the resistors.

Comment: Agreed with Igor. Resistor ladders are much more accurate and noise resistant. I would go for an I2C potentiometer such as AD5248.